# Rails 4 Repeating HTTP POST Request Spamming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, ruby-on-rails-4, spam

I have been working on a ruby on rails 4 application. For the most part the site is done, however I found a "security flaw" which allows me to capture the HTTP POST request via an intercepting proxy tool (Burp Suite). I can then send this POST request to a repeater, and re-submit the request over and over again. This effectively can be used to abuse my application and spam people. Before I go to launch this product, I need to fix this issue. This is where I need help. I would really like to avoid the usage of CAPTCHA, and I would like to keep the user-flow of the application as seamless as possible. So what are some good ways to prevent HTTP POST request spamming??

Thank you

Comment: You could implement some type of hackery of a MD5 checksum of the current time when the form gets posted. If the POST is older than X seconds, reject the POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/README.md) gem allow you to block or throttle requests based on pretty much anything in the rack environment.

A classic example is to throttle the number of login attempts for a username, which you could do with

```
Rack::Attack.throttle('logins/email', :limit => 6, :period => 60.seconds) do |req|
  req.params['email']} if req.path == '/login' && req.post?
end
```

You can define as many of these throttles as you like (within reason obviously)